# How do I write a function in JavaScript that creates an object and pushes that object into an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I have been working on this for many more hours than it calls for. I suspect that I am overthinking it or missing something simple, and could use another set of eyes to help me understand.

I want to write a function that creates a new object, in this case, an entry into a collection of architectural prints. After the object is created, I would like it to be pushed into an array that will store the entire collection. I am calling this array "collection" and am announcing it at the beginning of my code. With this code, when I call the function and enter my parameters, it gets returned undefined. What am I missing here?

```js
let collection = [];

function AddToCollection(titleName, artist, year) {
  titleName: titleName;
  artist: artist;
  year: year;
}; {
  collection.push();
};

AddToCollection();
```

Comment: Is this your entire code? Can you post a reproducible example?

Comment: `AddToCollection` has 3 arguments but you have passed none when you call it.

Comment: That is, frankly, just a mess. Think about where the function starts and ends. This about what an object initialiser looks like. Ask yourself what it is you are trying to push with that code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
let collection = []
collection.push(AddToCollection("title", "myartist","theyear"))

function AddToCollection(titleName, artist,year){ 

    return {titleName: titleName, artist: artist, year:year} 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to clean things up and organize it a bit. I'm not sure if this is what you intended, but it is functional.

```js
class Collection {
  collection = [];

  constructor(){}

  AddToCollection(titleName, artist, year) {
    const newObject = {
      titleName: titleName,
      artist: artist,
      year: year
    };
    this.collection.push(newObject);
  }
}

let c = new Collection();

c.AddToCollection("a", "b", "c");

console.log(c.collection);
```